# MicroStrategy Object Manager Is Changing Report's SQL Upon Migration

Tags: microstrategy

Please help. When I am using Object Manager to migrate my reports from one environment to another, the report SQL is changing, specifically, the metrics are not aggregating.

For example, on my source project, the reports SQL is:

```
Select
  a.customer,
  a.item,
  sum(a.price)
from tbl_prices a
group by
  a.customer,
  a.item;
```

But after migration, when I check on the target project, the report SQL will be:

```
Select
  a.customer,
  a.item,
  a.price
from tbl_prices a;
```

Does anyone happen to know the solution for this?

Best regards,
Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the MSTR Object Manager changes the query, but it's more probable that the projects you are migrating from and to are different.

I suspect that in the source environment you have some additional attribute mapped on `tbl_prices`, probably this additional attribute is also a key for the table.

In the target environment MSTR decides not to aggregate the metric probably because it thinks that `cusotmer` and `item` forms the primary key of your table (they should both have the key symbol when you edit the table) and there is no need to aggregate the prices.

Another solution can be to un-check  the flag `The key specified is the true key for the warehouse table`, this will tell to MSTR that an aggregation is needed. See screenshot below.

Personally I would use the flag only if required and try to fix the schema design first.

[image: The key specified is the true key for the warehouse table]

Personally I would use the flag only if required and try to fix the schema design first.

Comment: Thanks, that could be the solution.  But what I did to solve my problem is to include all the attributes of the report in the package, regardless if they are used in any data set or not.  Sometimes, we create an attribute and include it in the data set but then we remove it because somehow, we decided that it is not needed.  I guess when that attribute was created, it also created a key in the table definition.